# Mapbox Features Help (lines of different color, different thicknesses)

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I need help with creating lines of different colors and custom thicknesses

Some background first: I have an array data structure called this.colors. Each object in this array has two properties, ‘Code’ and ‘Hex’. This array has like 155 different objects, all of the said format.

Another data structure that is referenced is this.data, whose content isn’t important, but all that is needed to be known about it is that it has a numerical attribute to it, to which I iterate through to find the max value of that numerical attribute. This ended up not being used in the uncommented version of the below code, but its referenced in the commented stuff.

This is the code I currently have that is supposed to do I want it to do:

```
addLayerToMap() {
    this.map.on('load', () => {
        this.map.addSource('object1', {
            type: 'geojson',
            data: this.locationGeojson
        });
        this.map.addSource('lines', {
            type: 'geojson',
            data: this.linesGeojson
        });

        let max = 0;
        for (const row of this.data) {
            if (row.VALUE > max) {
                max = row.VALUE;
            }
        }

        this.map.addLayer({
            id: 'locations',
            type: 'circle',
            source: 'locations',
            paint: {
                'circle-color': 'red',
                'circle-radius': [
                'interpolate',
                ['linear'],
                ['get', 'imports'],
                this.import_min,
                5,
                this.import_max,
                15
                ]
            }
        });

        let counter = 0;
        let lineColor = '';
        this.linesGeojson.features.forEach(feature => {
            this.locationsGeojson.features.forEach(feature1 => {
                if ((feature.properties.location === feature1.properties.location) && (feature)) {
//***HERE***
                    if (feature.properties.id == 'A') {
                        lineColor = '#000000';
                    } else if (feature.properties.id == 'B') {
                        lineColor = '#FF0000';
                    } 

                    if (this.showLines) {
                        this.map.addLayer({
                            id: //some custom id,
                            type: 'line',
                            source: 'lines',
                            paint: {
                                'line-color': lineColor,
                                'line-width': [
                                    'interpolate',
                                    ['exponential', 2],
                                    ['get', 'imports'],
                                    this.import_min,
                                    3,
                                    this.import_max,
                                    15,
                                ],
                                //'line-width': 5*feature.properties.imports/max,
                                //'line-color': '#939393' //#939393, featureColor.Hex
                                /*'line-color': [
                                    'match',
                                    ['get', 'feature.properties.id'],
                                    "A01",
                                    '#000000',
                                    'C13-C15',
                                    '#00FF00',
                                    '#939393'
                                ]*/
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    counter++;
                }//working
                //counter++;
            })
        })
//other code that isn't relevant 
    });
}
```

Note that the first ‘this.map.addLayer’ call does work. It should add the object with id ‘locations’

As you can see in my code above, there are a number of commented lines of code where I tried various ways of setting 'line-color', all of which didn't work.

Here are my questions:

(1) How can I add lines of different colors (specifically for the ‘paint’ attribute in this.map.addLayer)? I initially tried this at the place in the code marked by HERE, but it doesn’t seem to work (it ended up only being lines of one color though I know my data has data of both categories). The logic there is that I would take a small subset of my data (all of whose ‘code’ value is either ‘A’ or ‘B’) and I would compare the code value to ‘A’ and ‘B’. Depending on which one is true, I would assign the corresponding Hex value to the variable lineColor. Then, in the this.map.addLayer function, I would just set ‘line-color’ to the variable lineColor.

Note that I have tried

```
'line-color': [
    'match',
    ['get', 'feature.properties.id'],
    "A01",
    '#000000',
    'C13-C15',
    '#00FF00',
    '#939393'
]
```

but all the lines turned out to be grey (#939393) even though I know my data set has entries whose id's are 'A01' or 'C13-C15' (I saw this post: [How to paint the result of a filter in MAPBOX a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402115/how-to-paint-the-result-of-a-filter-in-mapbox-a-different-color), but it didn't seem to help)

Furthermore, is there a way for me to iterate through this.colors and find the corresponding ‘Hex’ value for a given code?

(2) Currently the way I am setting ‘line-width’ doesn’t seem to have a noticeable difference in width. Is the way I’m doing it correct? (I do have a large range like from 1,000,000 to 9,000,000, so it might be correct and its the range that’s causing them to look like the same width) I am fine with the scale being either ‘linear’ or ‘exponential’

Let me know if something in my question isn't clear and I'll try to make it clear. Thanks for any help!